# How to build project in mingw64 C++ compiler after changing compiler from MSVC2019 to mingw64?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mingw

I createad Qt project in MSVC2019 Kits and my project can built in this compiler. But i wanted change compiler to MinGW-64Bit because I can not download MSVC2019 some restricted reasons.

I was using prebuilt library that is PcapPlusPlus and it was MSCV2019. But when i changed the compiler to MinGW-64 Bit compiler i changed PcapPlusPlus PreBuilted Release to MinGW-64 Bit. And i updated project. But now i can not built my current work project. What is the problem?

I remembered, if i change compiler to another compiler i changed PcapPlusPlus Prebuilted Release from 'pcapplusplus-23.09-windows-vs2019-x64-release.zip' to 'pcapplusplus-23.09-windows-mingw64-x86_64-gcc-13.2.0.zip'. But I do not have another idea?

Thanks.